# How to pipe the FFmpeg output to multiple ffplay?

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, pipe

I use the following command to pipe the FFmpeg output to 2 ffplay , but it doesn't work.

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -t 10 -i input.avi -force_key_frames 00:00:00.000 -tune zerolatency -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -f mpegts output.ts  -f avi -vcodec copy  -an - | ffplay -i - -f mpeg2video - | ffplay -i -
```

How can I pipe the FFmpeg output to 2 (or more) ffplay?

I saw [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162870/how-to-pipe-a-command-output-to-multiple-programs) but it doesn't work for ffplay. (it is for Linux but my OS is windows)

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's some kind of `Tee-Object` (alias `tee`) in PowerShell but I'm not sure if it's similar to the one on Linux. You can try:

`ffmpeg -re -i [...] -f mpegts - | tee >(ffplay -) | ffplay -`

An alternative is to output to a multicast port on the local subnetwork:

`ffmpeg -re -i [...] -f mpegts udp://224.0.0.1:10000`

You can then connect as many clients as you require on the same address/port:

`ffplay udp://224.0.0.1:10000`

Comment: How about the multicast?