# Pipe ffmpeg output as mjpeg on multicast port?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, h.264

I am trying to open a h.264 encoded stream from an IP camera, re-encode and stream it to a multicast address on my local subnet.

Found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662523/how-to-pipe-the-ffmpeg-output-to-multiple-ffplay) that seems to describe what I'd like to achieve but I am running into several issues.

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://192.168.0.11/stream1.sdp mpegts udp://239.168.0.1:11000
```

and I am receiving this output:

```
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001531da0ad40] no frame!
[rtsp @ 000001531d9b9700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
-- Above is repeated dozens of times
[rtsp @ 000001531d9b9700] RTP: missed 8 packets
[rtsp @ 000001531d9b9700] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Unknown: none (meta / 0x6174656D)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[rtsp @ 000001531d9b9700] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none (bdat / 0x74616462)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.0.11/stream1.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : DTC
    comment         : Pagos
  Duration: N/A, start: 1557.106222, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service #1
      service_provider: DTC
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (vid1 / 0x31646976), yuv420p(progressive), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Unknown: none (meta / 0x6174656D)
    Stream #0:2: Unknown: none (bdat / 0x74616462)
  No Program
    Stream #0:3: Data: epg
[NULL @ 000001531e5aa940] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'mpegts'
mpegts: Invalid argument
```

Where am I going wrong? I am quite inexperienced in this field but determined to learn more.

Thank you in advance for any pointers on how to go about this..

Comment: For a start, `ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.11/stream1.sdp -c:v mjpeg -q:v 6 -f mpegts udp://239.168.0.1:11000`

Comment: @Gyan Thank you. The output isn't viewable with ffplay udp://<address>. I tried to replace my live stream with "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" and I was able to view a frame or two but this is way too slow for my needs. Plainly speaking, I want to receive the h.264 feed on my machine, but I want to convert it to a mjpeg stream in as close to real-time as possible. Is this a very computationally expensive procedure, hence why I am not able to view the feed in 'real-time' ?  Many thanks

Comment: Ok, it turns out that MJPEG is not officially supported in MPEG-TS. Try `ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.11/stream1.sdp -vsync cfr -c:v mjpeg -q:v 6 -f mjpeg udp://239.168.0.1:11000` and then `ffplay -f mjpeg -i udp://239.168.0.1:11000`